# adding option to select with json

Tags: jquery, json, combobox, each

How can I run over this array and add the values to a combobox if they do not yet exist in that combobox? (remark: the values -the year- are already stored before adding them to the combobox):

```
[{"id":3,"year":2015},{"id":2,"year":2014},{"id":1,"year":2013}]
```

EDIT : this is the working solution without check for duplicates

```
function reloadPayments() {
    $.get('PHPCalls.php?CallID=GetPaymentList', function(payments) {
        $.each(payments, function(i,o) {
            $('#paymentList')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .val(obj.id)
                .html(obj.year));
        });
    }, 'json');
}
```

The combobox

```
<form id="formgroup" class="formstyle" action="*" method="POST">                  
    <label for="paymentList"> Kies een jaartal</label>
    <select id="paymentList" name="paymentList" class="txt">
        <option value="-2">Selecteer...</option>
        <option value="-1">Nieuw...</option>
        <?php
            foreach(Payment::getAll() as $payment)
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$payment->id.'">'.$payment->year.'</option>';
            }                      
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may be  executing an unnecessary `.each()` on the JSON array. I've set up a fiddle here... it's not a perfect match because it wasn't clear how the function was being invoked and I didn't use AJAX, but assuming your array is accurate, this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/poce6jzn/

If I'm understanding what you're trying to accomplish (the example above should add 3 options to the combobox - one for each year), you want to cut out that second `.each()` loop and replace `obj.id` and `obj.year` with `o.id` and `o.year`

For future reference, if you use google chrome, there's a variety of tools available to debug/visualize JSON/other arrays. One that I find particularly useful is [console.dir(obj)](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoledirobject) which dumps the whole array in an easy to read parsed format.

EDIT: this is to answer the comment about duplicates..

You could loop through the existing options and check if they exist:

Before the append statement, check the existing items aren't in the list, then append them

```
duplicateFlag = false;
$('#boxWithElements option').each(function(){
     if ( obj.id == this.value ) {
          duplicateFlag = true; 
     }
});

if (duplicateFlag === false) { 
     $('#paymentList')
          .append($("<option></option>")
          .val(obj.id)
          .html(obj.year));
}
```

Comment: thx for the console-link. Adding ', 'json' as extra parameter to my $.get was also necessary but so far the values aren't added yet. Looking further.

Comment: hmm.. `$.get()` shouldn't necessarily require 'json'.. the default is 'intelligent guess' according the jquery documentation.. I would be surprised if you needed that. Step one would be to look at this in chrome: `$.get('PHPCalls.php?CallID=GetPaymentList', function(payments) {console.dir(payments)});`

Comment: if i use console.dir(payment) the 'json' is necessary otherwise every single character from [ till ] is seen as object. It works now with the 'json'

Comment: how can I avoid having double values in the dropdownlist?

Comment: Double values? Do you mean duplicate? That could be slightly trickier depending on the data.. if you update your question I will update my  answer

Comment: Duplicate indeed. When selecting a year, a drag and drop-form appears. For a new list I got to select 'new', fill in an inputbox (id=year). When dropping the first item, the list is being saved. When saved, the new year should be added to the combobox. Saving the whole form happens through ajax so there is no page-reloading.  That seems tricky indeed for my level :-)